# GCP Pub/Sub communication between projects

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a Require authentication Cloud Run application created in project B with service accounts: test
In project A I have a pubsub topic: ProjectATopic

I deployed cloud run and add permission to the ss:test in project B: roles/pubsub.editor

In project A I gave permissions to the ss:test: roles/pubsub.editor and roles/cloudrun.invoker.

In project B I created subscription with topic: "projects/ProjectA/topics/ProjectATopic"
And set push enpoint to the cloud run.

When I published message from ProjectATopic I gave:

```
POST 403 0 B0 msAPIs-Google
```

But if I change cloud run security settings from: Require authentication to
Allow unauthenticated invocations. It works. What do I should change?

**EDIT**

I noticed I have this problem even in the same project.

In my terraform I create:

```
resource "google_service_account" "cloud_run_service_account" {
  account_id = "testss"
}

resource "google_project_iam_member" "pubsub_editor" {
  project = "testproject"
  role    = "roles/pubsub.editor"
  member  = "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.cloud_run_service_account.email}"
}

resource "google_project_iam_member" "pubsub_editor" {
  project = "testproject"
  role    = "roles/pubsub.subscriber"
  member  = "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.cloud_run_service_account.email}"
}

resource "google_project_iam_member" "run_invoker" {
  project = "testproject"
  role    = "roles/run.invoker"
  member  = "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.cloud_run_service_account.email}"
}

resource "google_pubsub_topic" "test_topic" {
  name = "test_topic"
}

resource "google_pubsub_subscription" "test_sub" {
  name = "test_sub"
  topic = "projects/testproject/topics/test_topic"


  push_config {
    push_endpoint = google_cloud_run_service.test_cr.status[0].url
  }

}

resource "google_cloud_run_service" "test_cr" {
  name = "test_cr"
  location = var.location
  template {
    spec {
      service_account_name = google_service_account.cloud_run_service_account.email

      containers {
        image = "gcr.io..."
      }
    }
  }

  traffic {
    percent = 100
    latest_revision = true
  }  
}
```

After terraform apply, everything deployed fine. I go to the GCP console -> pubsub topics -> test_topic and publish example message. In the logs in cloud run i see 403 errors

Comment: Your question is very confusing. Try rewriting to clearly define what you configured. It appears that you are trying to grant IAM roles in project A to access resources in project B. If you want to access a resource in project B, the IAM permissions must be granted in project B.

Comment: Agree with @JohnHanley, you have to grant the ss:test the Cloud Run invoker role on the Cloud Run service (or wider, on the Project hosting the Cloud Run service, here the project B)

Comment: @JohnHanley I edited the post. I have this problem even in the same project